# Design of a general-purpose handler for 'solver' class

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns

<sup>*A case where 'problem' should not be a problem in the title.*</sup>

I want to implement a solver (class Solver) for a collection of problems (all children of class Problem), which more or less share the same set of methods. My current design is like this:

In `solver.h`:

```
template<class P>
class Solver{
public:
    P* p;
    Solver(P* problem) : p(problem) {}
    void justDoIt(){
        p->step1();
        p->step2();
        p->step3();
        p->step4();
        p->step5();
    }
}
```

In `main.cpp`:
    #include "solver.h"

```
class A {
public:
    void step1() {}
    void step2() {}
    void step3() {}
    void step4() {}
    void step5() {}
};

class B: public A {
public:
    void step2() {}
    void step4() {}
};

class C: public A {
public:
    void step3() {}
    void step4() {}
    void step5() {}
};

int main(){
    B b;
    C c;
    Solver<B> sb(&b);
    Solver<C> sc(&c);
    sb.justDoIt();
    sc.justDoIt();
    return 0;
}
```

If I want to extend Solver for a new problem type, say C, and it

1. does nothing in `step1()`;
2. does `step2.5()` between `step2()` and `step3()`

Now calling `C c; Solver<C> sc(&c); c.justDoIt()`, I need to modify `A`, `B` and `Solver::justDoIt()` first.

Is there a scalable to design the interface that adding new problem types (all childern of `A`) for `Solver`?

PS: The current codebase I am about to modify has 47 types of problems all using the same `Solver` class. Minimal change is preferred.

How can I do it better?

Comment: Give each problem type a `justDoIt` member function that knows the steps for that problem type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Virtual Functions:

The first option that should come into mind is to use virtual functions:

Redefine your Problem-class to contain a pure virtual function (that means: every child needs to reimplement it):

```
class Problem{
  public:
  virtual void allSteps()=0;
};
```

Redefine your Solver to call this special function:

```
class Solver{
  public:
  Problem* p;

  Solver(Problem* prob):p(prob){}

  void solve(){
    p->allSteps();
  }
};
```

And add an implementation in every child-class:

```
class MyProblem: public Problem{
public:
  void step1(){
    std::cout << "step1\n";
  }
  void step2(){
    std::cout << "step1\n";
  }
  void stepx(int x){
    std::cout << "step"<<x<<"\n";
  }

  void allSteps(){
    step1();
    step2();
    stepx(3);
    stepx(4);
  }
};
```

And use your main-function as you did before:

```
int main() {
  MyProblem myP;
  Solver s(&myP);
  s.solve();
  return 0;
}
```

Try it here: http://ideone.com/NOZlI6

### Function-Pointers/Objects

This is a slightly more complex solution, but depending on your needs (e.g. executing only a single step and then do something else) it might better fit your needs.

Whenever you see something like "foo1","foo2","foo3",... you should think of an array or a vector. And the same can be applied to your Problem:

First of all, redefine your "Problem" class to take an arbitrary amount of function pointers - or using c++, function objects:

```
class Problem{
public:
  std::vector<std::function<void(void)>> functions;
};
```

Then all your Solver needs to do is to iterate over the function objects inside your Problems class:

```
class Solver{
public:
  Problem* p;

  Solver(Problem* prob):p(prob){}

  void solve(){
    for(auto func : p->functions)
    func();
  }
};
```

In order to register your classes functions properly, you need to remember that member-functions have an additional "hidden" parameter "this" that is a pointer to the class itself. But we can use std::bind to make a void(void) function out of any function we have. An alternative would be to use static functions, but since this should be easy to figure out, i will use the more complex way here:

```
class MyProblem: public Problem{
public:
  void step1(){
    std::cout << "step1\n";
  }
  void step2(){
    std::cout << "step1\n";
  }
  void stepx(int x){
    std::cout << "step"<<x<<"\n";
  }

MyProblem(){
    functions.push_back(std::bind(&MyProblem::step1,this));
    functions.push_back(std::bind(&MyProblem::step2,this));
    functions.push_back(std::bind(&MyProblem::stepx,this,3));
    functions.push_back(std::bind(&MyProblem::stepx,this,4));
}
```

};

Your main-function will then be unaffected:

```
int main() {
  MyProblem myP;
  Solver s(&myP);
  s.solve();
  return 0;
}
```

Try it here: http://ideone.com/BmIYVa

Comment: Yes `virtual void stepX() {};` is the current way of adding specialised step for each problem class; the result is a bloated, one-size-fit-all `justDoIt()`. As for you second suggestion, `Solver::justDoIt()` is slightly more nuanced. It has loops and conditions for each type of problem.

Answer (score 1):

At least to me this design seems like a (pardon the technical jargon) mess.

Right now, `Solver` has intimate knowledge of the internals of `Problem`. Further, it appears there's no way for `Solver` to do its job *without* intimate knowledge of the internals of `Problem` either.

At least in my estimation, what you've called `Solver::justDoIt()` should really be `Problem::operator()`. If *many* of the `Problem`s use `step1()` through `step5()` as you've shown in `Solver`, you can provide that implementation by default in `Problem` itself, then those that need to override that will provide their own implementations:

```
class Problem { 
protected:
    virtual void step1() {} 
    // ...
    virtual void step5() {}
public:
     virtual void operator()() { 
         step1();
         step2();
         step3();
         step4();
         step5();
     }
};

class B : public Problem { 
protected:
    void step2() {}
    void step4() {}
};

class C : public Problem {
protected:
    virtual void step3() {}
    virtual void step4() {}
    virtual void step5() {}
};
```

Then the main looks something like this:

```
int main() { 
    B b;
    C c;

    b();
    c();
}
```

Or, if you prefer shorter code:

```
int main() { 
    B()();
    C()();
}
```

This creates a temporary object of each type, then invokes the `operator()` on that temporary object. I'm not particularly fond of it, but some people think it's great.

Comment: `B()()` only executes 2 out of 5 steps, not what I wanted. Moving `Solver::justDoIt()` into an operator of each problem class seems like a lot of duplicate code.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your intent--I've corrected the answer. You'd override a `stepN` function if you want the derived class to carry out that specific function differently. You'd override `operator()` if (and only if) you wanted to change it to do something other than calling `step1()` through `step5()` in sequence.

Comment: Your proposal has the advantage of confining all changes to code base within the newly defined class, but disdvantage of duplicate code. I will think about it.

Comment: The actual `Solver::justDoIt()` is more complicated than `step1(); step2(); // ...`, with loops and conditions, different from problem to problem and  `operator()` would be overridden for all existing 47 classes.

Comment: @user103500: Let me put things simply: naming the function `operator()` instead of `justDoIt` doesn't change anything. Either you already need separate code for the 47 different types, or else you don't need separate code when you change the name. This can change *where* you put the code, but shouldn't change much (if anything) with respect to duplication or lack thereof (but if you want to go into much more detail, we'll probably need to see at least *some* idea of what we're trying to deal with).